# Hiding theorem in document, but keeping definition for reference

Tags: theorems

I am using restatable for theorems so that I can restate them in my appendix. I don't want the some of the original theorem statements to appear. Is there a way to hide the original statement, while keeping the definition\label so that it can referenced?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{thm-restate}

\begin{document}

 \begin{restatable}[Thm 1]{theorem}{thmone}\label{thm1}

       Thm 1

 \end{restatable}

\thmone*

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can use as a foundation? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and contain your relevant packages, a (couple of) theorem(s) in the main body and some `\restatable` theorems in an appendix.

Comment: What should `\thm1` do?

Comment: \thm1* is how the thm is restated, so it simply puts in the thm statement there

Comment: Does \hphantom work? (That is, put \hphantom around the restatable environment.)

Comment: A `\label` makes an annotation in the `.aux` file only if it the text where it appears eventually is typeset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one workaround - placing a `\nexttheorem{<label>}` in order to obtain an in-sequence numbering of a `theorem` and placing a `fixedtheorem` environment in your appendix with a `\ref{<label>}` to the original position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}

\newcommand{\nexttheorem}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{theorem}%
  \label{#1}%
  \ignorespaces}

\newenvironment{fixedtheorem}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{#1}%
   \renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}%
   \begin{theorem}}
  {\end{theorem}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

See Theorems~\ref{thm:first}, \ref{thm:second} and~\ref{thm:third}.

\begin{theorem}[first]\label{thm:first}
This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{restatable}[second]{theorem}{thmtwo}\label{thm:second}
This is the second theorem.
\end{restatable}

\nexttheorem{thm:third}

\section*{Appendix}

\thmtwo*

\begin{fixedtheorem}{\ref{thm:third}}[third]
This is the third theorem.
\end{fixedtheorem}

\end{document}
```